# How to show array in email template file?

Tags: magento-1.9

**In my controller file:**

```
$vars = array('product_name' => $data['productname'],
                'sku' => $data['sku'],
                'qty' => $data['qty'],
                'customprice' => $model1->getInquiryPrice(),
                'options' => $option,

                );



echo "<pre>"; print_r($vars); die;

Output:



Array
(
    [product_name] => testing demo custom image
    [sku] => demo
    [qty] => 2
    [customprice] => 34.0000
    [options] => Array
        (
            [color] => red
            [length] => 12
        )

)
```

Email template file (inquiry.html):

Path: `app/locale/en_US/template/email/inquiry.html`

```
 <table border="1" style="max-width:100%">

                             <tr class="action-content">

                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Sku</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>options</th>

                              </tr>

                              <tr class="action-content">

                                <td>{{var product_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{var sku}}</td>
                                <td>{{var qty}}</td>
                                <td>{{var customprice}} </td>
                                 <td>{{var options}}</td>

                              </tr>
</table>
```

var product_name,var sku,var qty, var customprice is showing the correct output, but var options is not showing correct output in email template file.

**Output:**

```
                             

                                Product Name
                                Sku
                                Quantity
                                Price
                                options

                              

                              

                                testing demo custom image
                                demo
                                2
                                23.0000 
                                Array
```

Comment: You have to pass array with key like, color1=> red, color2=>green and after you can access {{var options.color1}} and {{var options.color2}}

Comment: please show hot to set $option in your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to pass `options` as a string.

```
$allOptions = implode(", ", $option);
$vars = array('product_name' => $data['productname'],
            'sku' => $data['sku'],
            'qty' => $data['qty'],
            'customprice' => $model1->getInquiryPrice(),
            'options' => $allOptions,

            );
```

Now in email template:

`{{var options}}` should give you `green, red`

**UPDATE**

If your $option will always give data in `Color, Length` format then you can add like this:

```
$allOptions = "Color: ". $option[0]. " & Length: ". $option[1];
```

Rest is the same.

**UPDATE 2**

If key is diff then go to foreach

```
$allOptions = null;
foreach($option as $key => $opt){
   $allOptions .= $key . ": ". $opt. " \n"; 
}
```

Comment: yes, it is working , but how to show key ?  like color: red & length: 12

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: No, it is not always give same data, So how will i know which keys to use, because each time no. of elements in array can differ. & thanks for your effort

Comment: Then, you can achieve this from foreach. Check my update.