# How to use nested array in email template

Tags: email-templates

I have a nested array that I am passing as templateVar.

```
setTemplateVars(['details' => $arr])
```

The array($arr) is

```
[0] => [
        ["key1"]=>value1
        ["key2]=>value2
]
[1]=>[
        ["key1"]=>value1
        ["key2]=>value2
]
.
.
.
All arrays have same keys.
```

I have tried both updates mentioned in [How to show array in email template file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150169/how-to-show-array-in-email-template-file)

In the template file, I'm trying to use it as -

```
<?php foreach($details as $detail) : ?>
           <p>{{trans ' %val' val=$detail.key1}}</p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I cannot pass it as a string as the array can be an array of 100s of arrays with same keys.

Comment: you can use foreach loop

Comment: Have you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Providing you an static way to get the specific value of array key. You can pass it like this:

```
setTemplateVars(['details' => $arr[0]->key1]) //get key1 value from array 0

setTemplateVars(['details' => $arr[1]->key1]) //get key1 value from array 1
```

Using `foreach loop`

<s>foreach($arr as $detail){
       setTemplateVars(['details'=> $detail["key1"]);}</s>

```
<?php foreach($details as $detail) : ?>
    <p>{{trans ' %val' val = $detail["key1"]}}</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use foreach? I've tried -
foreach($details as detail):
<p>$detail.key1</p> - This doesn't work

Comment: check updated ans

Comment: How to use this is the template file?

Comment: can you update your question with your code in the template file

Comment: can you try this    `<?php foreach($details as $detail) : ?>
        <p>{{trans ' %val' val = $detail["key1"]}}</p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: It's still not working. It seems as though the phtml is not parsing template variables. I tried `->setTemplateVars(['detail' => 'hello' ])` and in the phtml file - `<p>{{$detail}}</p>` and it still shows {{$detail}} in the email